# Validating Facebook page name

Tags: javascript, facebook

I would like to let a user enter a facebook page name and validate that it is a facebook page and nothing else.

To accomplish that I've used ajax to call graph.facebook.com/{str} where {str} is a pageName a user is requested to enter, but the problem is that any string can be entered and if a user enters a string which is a facebook profile, it will return a facebook object.

How do I validate using graph.facebook.com/{str} that {str} is a valid facebook page name ?

I've tried using graph.facebook.com/search?q={str}&type=page but it returns close results too even if the {str} that was entered wasn't found.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Graph API I would suggest you to instead use the [Page FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page) which is indexable by the `name` field, and would only return data if the `name` corresponds to a Facebook Page and not for a User.

**Edit**

```
select name from page where name='ign'
```

Which would give you the result for IGN's page, but if you do the same for any user it would return nothing.

Comment: Thanks, can you give an example on how FQLing for a fb page ?

Comment: @Alon Sorry just forgot to added it. I have corrected my mistake do check

Answer (score 0):

Some fanpages don't have short username:

```
https://www.facebook.com/pages/Fanpage-name/FANPAGE_ID
```

in this case, you should send FANPAGE_ID instead of username. Valid fanpage will have fields like

```
 "is_published": true,
 "likes": 27134,
```

check graph api result for public profile:

```
 http://graph.facebook.com/zuck
```

and fanpage:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/facebook
```